# How to manipulate numpy arrays in this way?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (28,28) array `a`. And I want to obtain a (28,28,3) array `b` s.t. `b[i][j][0] = b[i][j][1] = b[i][j][2] = a[i][j]`.

Is there any numpy shortcut to do this without tedious for loops?

Comment: Just a side note: arrays support multidimensional indexing. Instead of `b[i][j][0]` you can and should use `b[i, j, 0]` which is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((28,28))
>>> b = np.dstack((a,a,a))
>>> a.shape
(28, 28)
>>> b.shape
(28, 28, 3)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> b = np.dstack((a,a,a))
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> b
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
```

Comment: `dstack` will copy elements, while `repeat` will not - for this array size the performance difference may be unimportant, but for large arrays it can be drastic.

Comment: @BrandonDube Thanks for your tip.

Comment: @BrandonDube _while repeat will not_ That's news to me ... and to `np.shares_memory`: `np.shares_memory(b, b.repeat(1, 1))` -> `False`

Comment: @PaulPanzer So, who should I believe? I choose you!

Comment: That's very kind ;-) But no need to make it a matter of belief. Just check for yourself using `np.shares_memory`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer `np.shares_memory` is new to me.. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You can append an axis to `a` and then repeat it `n=3` times:

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(28, 28)
>>> b = np.repeat(np.atleast_3d(a), repeats=3, axis=-1)
>>> b.shape 
(28, 28, 3)
```

And as required,

```
>>> np.all(a == b[...,0])
True
>>> np.all(b[...,0] == b[...,1])
True
>>> np.all(b[...,1] == b[...,2])
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate `b` and use broadcasting:

```
b = np.empty(a.shape + (3,), a.dtype)
b[...] = a[..., None]
```

If you only need read access, then a very efficient way is creating a strided view:

```
c = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, a.shape + (3,), a.strides + (0,))
```

This shares its data with `a` meaning that when you write to `c`, `a` will also change. Moreover along the last axis the stride is zero meaning that for example c[1, 1, 0] and c[1, 1, 2] are the same memory, change one and the other will also change. If that's not desired make a copy:

```
b = c.copy()
```

Comment: You would need `writable = False` to actually make it *read only*. Without it, you still have *write access*.

Comment: @Divakar just my way of saying don't write unless you know what you're doing. Btw. saw me winning an argument below the other answer using the `np.shares_memory` you showed me the other day?

Comment: Congratulations on the win? :) Well you know it's good to share info, the pun not intended ;)